# Word "Model" is missing in text input binding when using TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

Using below model, and using TextBoxFor, I see the word `Model` is missing from `id` property of html input

ModelView class:

```
public class ProductUpdateViewModel
{
    public Product NewItem { get; set; }
    // more properties here
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProducts", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="cssProduct" style="background-color:blue">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewItem.Name)
    </div>
}
```

HTML source:

```
<input id="NewItem_Name" name="NewItem.Name" type="text" value="">
```

I expect to see `name="Model.NewItem.Name"` for text input, but I see `name="NewItem.Name"` instead and this cause to get null for that input when getting Model in post-back

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProducts(ProductUpdateViewModel model)
{
    //model.NewItem.Name is null here
}
```

**Edit:**

If I use below code in View instead of using TextBoxFor, it will work properly

```
@Html.TextBox("Model.NewItem.Name")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you expect to see 'Model'? It's only meaningful to the Razor engine and should not feature in the rendered HTML.

Comment: Because if I use name="Model.NewItem.Name" it will work. so I conclude that it's the correct name that has to be generated.

Comment: I suspect if it works when you code it manually, it's because your parameter name in the controller happens to be 'model' and it binds automatically. But the HTML Helper in the view can't know that, so can't generate the correct name.

Comment: but it is working!

Comment: Yes, and I suggested why it might be working. The question - to test my theory - is does it still work if you change the name of the parameter in the controller? BTW, is this Core or MVC5?

Comment: Okay, I've tried reproducing this in MVC5 as best I can based on what you've given. It works if the `name` in the generated HTML is 'NewItem.Name' or 'Model.NewItem.Name' but not 'AnythingElse.NewItem.Name'. That's pretty much what one would expect.

If it's not working for you for 'NewItem.Name' then I suspect there must be some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect to see name="Model.NewItem.Name"

Why do you expect to see that? It's not how this works and neither is the binding.

To see it as you expect it, you should be binding with the following (which will fail as there is not Model object in your model):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model.NewItem.Name)
```

Also just because you declare the method variable `ProductUpdateViewModel model`, it does not mean that the binding name should be `name="Model.NewItem.Name"`. It should be what it is, the binding is agnostic to the method paramater name, it only just expects an object.

Comment: This is not working as m.Model is not defined. Please see my Edit on question to see why I'm saying the TextBoxFor should add "Model" for complex object structure.